# How to find number of same elements in list Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I have a question about the topic,

I know the list of Prolog works like [head, (tail)] but is there any function or magical touch(sample codes) to find number of elements in the list?. Is there any way to get number of same elements in the list then compare the list or the unique element in it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is as follows:

```
get_uniq(List,Uniq) :-
    select(Uniq,List,SubList),   % chose an item from the list
    \+ member(Uniq,SubList).     % make sure it doesn't have a pair
```

%% added later

You can get full list of unique items with:

```
findall(N,get_uniq([2,1,4,3,2,5,1,4,3],N), Ns).
```

Comment: from rereading your question I'm not 100% that I asked it but I think I'm in the neighborhood.  Are you asking for something that removes duplicates?

Comment: If I clarify it, we have a list of numbers and each numbers' count in it 2. Like `[2,4,3,2,4,3]` and we have a unique one in it like `[2,3,5,3,2,4,4]` . The output must be "5" . Could you describe that what does this part exactly? `\+ member(Uniq,SubList)` Thank you for your support btw, I really appreciate it that.

Comment: \+ can be read as "not" so think of as not_member  (if that was a function that existed)

Comment: it works as recursive? or `uniq` has a meaning in prolog? (I'm a really beginner, please dont mind about my easy questions)

Comment: I was just using uniq as an abbreviation for unique (not built in functions).  

The get_uniq function uses prolog backtracking to work through all the possible solutions.  Try using select a few times at a prolog prompt to get a sense how it work.  Once you understand that the rest should fall into place.

findall is just a way to take something that can generate lots of solutions and collect them into one list.

Answer (score 3):

Library([aggregate](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate)) should be your first choice for this task.
In general

```erlang
?- L=[a,b,c,a],setof(C*E,aggregate(count,member(E,L),C),R).
L = [a, b, c, a],
R = [1*b, 1*c, 2*a].
```

which can be specialized to get a list of elements occurring once in this way

```erlang
?- L=[a,b,c,a],setof(E,aggregate(count,member(E,L),1),R).
L = [a, b, c, a],
R = [b, c].
```

Comment: So how can we list the ones that are not equal to 2 instead of the ones equal to 1?

L=[a, b, b, c, c, c, a],setof(E, aggregate(count,member(E,L), not equal to 2),R).

Comment: @eden: for instance, setof(E, (aggregate(count,member(E,L),N),N\=2)),R)